# run JS function after input, node

Tags: javascript, css, nodelist

I used `setInterval` for run the function but that will execute function 2 many times...

1. How to execute function after insert a value in to input
2. 1st input have different distance from rest of it
3. how move insert from 1 input to next one after insert val (tab option)

check sniper, wrote some letters and some spaces to see what i mean, for skip to another input press tab

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
  checkLen();
  fill();
}, 200);

function checkLen(){
 x = document.getElementById("letters").getElementsByTagName("input").length;
 y=x-1;
 z = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[y].value;
 if(z == " "){
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[y].style.opacity = 0;
 }
 
 if(x>0 && z.length>0){
  createLetter(x);
 }
 document.getElementsByTagName("input")[y].oninput = function() {checkLen()};
}

 function createLetter(x){
  num1=x+1;
  node = document.createElement("input");
        node.setAttribute("id", "letter-"+num1);
        node.setAttribute("maxlength", "1");
        node.setAttribute("type", "text");
        document.getElementById("letters").appendChild(node);
 }
 function fill(){
  text = "" ;
  x = document.getElementById("letters").getElementsByTagName("input").length;
  for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
   int =  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value;
   text = text +int;

  }
  document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = text;

 }
```

```css
body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: white;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 background-color: gray;
}
body *{
 display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
 [class*="col-"] {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

 input{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin:2px;

 }
  script{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="col-12" id="letters">
  <input id="letter-01" type="text" name="haslo" maxlength="1">
 </div>
 <div class="col-12">
  <p id="check"></p>
 </div>



</body>
```

Check snipper...
Also 1st input have diffrent distance than

Answer (score 2):

One quick tip for you, maybe can help. You can use event and bind method in jquery to detect if user insert value into input field.

```
$ ("#yourFieldID").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
    // some code
});
```

Also you can use propertychange event

```
 $('#yourFieldID').on('propertychange input', function () {
    //some code
 });
```

Pure JS way

```
document.getElementById("yourInput").oninput = () => { 
  console.log('user entered something'); 
}
```

Comment: i know i can do it in jquery, but i would like to use pure js

Comment: I have added JS way on my post, maybe can help.

Comment: In pure javascript it an be done by adding an event listener like explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: "document.getElementById("yourInput").oninput = () => { 
  console.log('user entered something'); 
}" wont work, id is specific for every input, and you cant say how many inputs will be on finish.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use jquery by just calling `.on("keypress",...)`, I've just replaced `window.setInterval(...)` and the best should be to use the event listner with a particular dom element

```js
$(document).on('keypress',function(e) {
  checkLen();
  fill();
});

function checkLen(){
 x = document.getElementById("letters").getElementsByTagName("input").length;
 y=x-1;
 z = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[y].value;
 if(z == " "){
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[y].style.opacity = 0;
 }
 
 if(x>0 && z.length>0){
  createLetter(x);
 }
 document.getElementsByTagName("input")[y].oninput = function() {checkLen()};
}

function createLetter(x){
  num1=x+1;
  node = document.createElement("input");
      node.setAttribute("id", "letter-"+num1);
      node.setAttribute("maxlength", "1");
      node.setAttribute("type", "text");
      document.getElementById("letters").appendChild(node);
}

function fill(){
  text = "" ;
  x = document.getElementById("letters").getElementsByTagName("input").length;
  for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
    int =  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value;
    text = text +int;

  }
  document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = text;

}
```

```css
body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: white;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 background-color: gray;
}
body *{
 display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
 [class*="col-"] {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

 input{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin:2px;

 }
  script{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="col-12" id="letters">
  <input id="letter-01" type="text" name="haslo" maxlength="1">
 </div>
 <div class="col-12">
  <p id="check"></p>
 </div>



</body>
```